# time.sleep blocks while loop in thread

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, python-multithreading

When I run a `While True` loop in thread and use time.sleep() function the loop stops looping.

I am using **this** code:

```
import threading
from time import sleep

class drive_worker(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(drive_worker, self).__init__()
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print('loop')
            #some code
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

To start the thread I am using **this** code:

```
thread = drive_worker()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stops looping"?

Comment: It just hangs. It is not printing 'loop' or is doing anything.

Comment: Is that code supposed to be a complete example? The `time.sleep` line will give a `NameError`. Also, once the thread starts, the script will immediately exit.

Comment: Assuming you change "from time import sleep" to just "import sleep" and add "thread = drive_worker()" and "thread.join()" to the code example, it works perfectly fine on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You imported `sleep` as

`from time import sleep`

so you have to call sleep in `run()` as `sleep(0.5)` or you have to change import as

`import time`

which I do not recommend.

Comment: Why do you not recommend to use `import time`?

Comment: Well both have their own pros and cons. If you need to only use just one item, assuming OP was just demonstrating the looping nature, there is no need for him to import the whole package. Unless you need to import a lot of item from time or say module_x i don't see the reason to do so. also typing `module.item` so often could be a real mess. :)

Answer (score 2):

The loop stops because you flagged the thread as `daemon`.
The program terminates when there are only daemon threads left running.

```
self.daemon = True # remove this statement and the code should work as expected
```

Or make the main thread wait for the the daemon thread to finish

```
dthread = drive_worker()
# no call to start method since your constructor does that
dthread.join() #now the main thread waits for the new thread to finish
```